# No Linux variant works on my Virtual Box - System freezes after booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine

> No Linux variant works on my Virtual Box - System freezes after booting..

I'm currently running Windows 8 on a new laptop with Intel Haswell and Nvidia Maxwell architecture. Also the system has 8 GB of memory (DDR3). The main OS is Windows 8 (64-bit) Professional.

I've tried installing both Kali Linux and Ubuntu Linux without luck. In both cases I've activated PAE/NX and given the system 2 GB of memory, 1 CPU-core and plenty of storage.

However, Kali Linux boots (at best) to login screen where it freezes. It is not even possible to install Ubuntu, as the picture at the bottom illustrates. Both Linux variants has been downloaded in 32-bit versions, since that is what the Virtual Box supports ?

What could the problem be - any solutions to it ?

**Kali Linux:**
(This picture shows Kali Linux freezes before login screen - I've been waiting over 30 min. for the system to boot properly)
[image]

**Ubuntu Linux:**
[image]

Comment: Virtualbox supports both x86 and x64 operating systems but there is no technical reason x86 shouldn't work.  Do you have hardware virtualization enabled?

Comment: I can only check for Hardware Virtualization in BIOS right ? Can you tell anything from the Error Message Ubuntu is displaying on installation startup ?

Comment: If I were to guess its connected to PAE/NX

Comment: You are right. According to Intel tool Virtualization is not enabled. This is my CPU: http://ark.intel.com/products/75119/Intel-Core-i7-4702MQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz. Indeed it has support for Virtualization, but it can't be turned on in BIOS (vendor laptop). How can I turn it on ?